# How to make a dynamically retrieved image clickable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have retrieved an image and its corresponding data dynamically, in which I want to make the image clickable which will redirect to a webpage.
How can I achieve this using angularJs.

I am using only angularJs, no jquery.

Comment: what have u tried ? , show us some code . without code it would be difficult to update u

Comment: Use ng-click for that purpose.

Comment: @Bhavesh - Sample code please!

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see you can assign the values to an object and then use that object on the image tag. If you want to make any other changes on click as well then you can use ng-click as shown below then use $location.url.

```
$scope.object = {};
$scope.object.filepath = filepath;
$scope.object.redirectURL = redirectURL

<img ng-src="object.filepath" ui-sref="{{object.redirectURL}}" />

$scope.redirect = function(redirectURL)
{
    $location.url(redirectURL);
};  

<img ng-src="object.filepath" ng-click="redirect(redirectURL)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click on the image element. You can handle the click event in your controller where you can navigate to the webpage.

In your controller you can redirect the page to the webpage url.

```
$scope.goToWebpage = function(imageParam){
window.location.href = "http://UrlToWebpage.com";
}
```

Alternatively you can wrap the image inside an anchor tag. On clicking the image the page will be redirected to the specified url mentioned in href.

```
<a href="http://UrlToWebpage.com" >
<img src="sourceToImage" />
</a>
```